# Printing folder contents to a text file in SAS

Tags: sas

Is there a way I can have SAS print the contents of a folder to a .txt file.
For reference this is how one can do it using DOS.
https://www.groovypost.com/howto/microsoft/list-directory-contents-to-a-printable-and-readable-txt-file/

Comment: Google with the term "Directory listing + Language" to find the answer to this https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/mcrolref/n0js70lrkxo6uvn1fl4a5aafnlgt.htm

Comment: https://communities.sas.com/t5/forums/searchpage/tab/message?advanced=false&allow_punctuation=false&q=directory%20listing

Comment: First there is no DOS CMD (CMD.EXE is Windows or OS/2. MS-DOS uses COMMAND.COM). Second there is no reason to run CMD as administrator to print folder content. I would stay away from such tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure - you can use this macro:  https://core.sasjs.io/mp__dirlist_8sas.html

Usage:

```
%mp_dirlist(path=/some/location,outds=work.contents)

data _null_;
  set work.contents;
  file "/some/file.txt";
  put filepath;
run;
```